# flash builder vs coscos2d for iOS

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, flash-builder

I am considering launching a somewhat larger game project for mobile devices (mainly iOS) that uses box2d and am considering using Flash Builder. There are lots of games with great performance built on coscos2d and our staff is fluent both in coscos2d and flash builder.

What apps are out that to look at developed with flash builder?

It seems like flash builder might be kind of new to have a lot of solid games so if you are developing a game with Flash Builder how is it going?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I feel I have by far much more control with cocos2d than Flash Builder. I don't know much about Flash anyway. However, I can at least tell you that I have a rather large cocos2d game project, and so far, we never had an issue regarding features.

Cocos2d supports all Apple platforms, and there are some nice ports for Android and such too.

Anyway, I think this depends too much on your actual game project. What key features it has?